# Have exception in OpenCV when converting an image to grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv

Have strange error.
 I try to convert Image to grayscale and,after that print result matrix to file, but get exception:

> "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF965E31F28 in ConsoleApplication1.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
>   0x00000041305AF2A0.

Following code is below.
 Can somebody say me when I made mistake?

```
int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    string fname;
    cin >> fname;

    cv::Mat img = readImage(fname);

    cv::Mat grayImg(img.size(), CV_64FC1);
    if (img.channels() == 3)
    {
        cvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        img.copyTo(grayImg);
    }
    printImg(grayImg);

    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
void printImg(cv::Mat &img)
{
    cout << "---------//------\n";
    if (img.empty())
    {
        cout << "Empty Image\n";
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < img.size().height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.size().width; j++)
        {
            cout << img.at<double>(i, j) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------//------\n";
}
```

error in string

```
cout << img.at<double>(i, j) << " ";
```

Comment: Your debugger should tell you. Learn to use the debugger as this is the right tool to inspect and analyze a program's behavior. There is no way to be a programmer without knowing the debugger, among other analytical tools.

Comment: how debugger should tell me where is problem ? I can say, that error in string "            cout << img.at<double>(i, j) << " ";   "

Comment: Well, learn what a debugger is? The message indicates a crash most likely due to an access violation, i.e. a segmentation fault, start the program in a debugger and see the line where it crashes, find the source of the bad access, etc.

Comment: A stack trace tells you most of what you need to figure out your error.

Comment: I did this, and found the line when it crashes. also, I saw, that in grayScale.data there are right values(not empty etc)

Comment: you can't convert to grayscale and to a different data type in a single step. try .cvtColor first and .convertTo afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV functions are throwing exceptions if something happens. You can see them if you will put your code inside try-catch block:

```
int main() try
{
    // your code here
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

When something bad happens - just look into terminal output and you will undertsand the reason.

**UPDATE:**
After you got the error message - its easy to solve it. You are expecting to have 64-bit double values, but your greyscale Mat it 8-bit unsigned char

I sugeest this changes in your code that should help:

```
cv::Mat grayImg;
if (img.channels() == 3)
    cvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
else if (img.channels() == 4)
    cvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
else grayImg = img;
// here grayImg is 8-bit unsigned char
// change it to doubles:
cv::Mat gray64bit;
grayImg.convertTo(gray64bit, CV_64FC1);
printImg(gray64bit);
```

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file d:\programfiles\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 919

Comment: do you know what is mean?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have to read an image then convert it to grayscale while OpenCV support convert image to grayscale when reading it by enum CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Next, the default imread you use will read image as BGR as CV_8U channel. You don't have to allocate grayImg, cvtColor will do it for you.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor

the grayImg will have same depth and size as original. So your

```
cout << img.at<double>(i, j) << " ";
```

produce the error.
It should be

```
cout << img.at<uchar>(i, j) << " ";
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, but what I must to do if I need to use double in cout ?

Comment: as the documentation said, your grayImg depth basing on img depth. So you just need to convert img using member function convertTo of cv::Mat. http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto
In your case, img.convertTo(img, CV_64FC3);